# google.visualisation is undefined using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

When i run the below I am getting `TypeError: google.visualisation is undefined[Learn More]`
the data is coming back from my .php file and I can see it when I do a console.log.
I am probably lost in with the callbacks or maybe someone can andvise otherwise?

I have tried to load the visualistion before i do my ajax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315250/jquery-load-google-visualization-api-with-ajax) but same error. I have also looked at other possible answers but I still cannot get it to work.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

console.log("hello world")
//alert("result")

$.ajax({
    url:"data.php",
    dataType : "JSON",
    success : function(result) {
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages':['corechart'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
            console.log(result);
            drawChart(result);                  
        });
    }
}); 

function drawChart(result) {

    var data = new google.visualisation.Datatable();
    data.addColumn('string','Name');
    data.addColumn('number','Quantity');
    var dataArray=[];
    $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
        dataArray.push([ obj.name, parseInt(obj.quantity) ]);
    });

    data.addRows(dataArray);

    var piechart_options = {
        title : 'Pie Chart: How Much Products Sold By Last Night',
        width : 400,
        height : 300
    }
    var piechart = new google.visualisation.PieChart(document
            .getElementById('piechart_div'));
    piechart.draw(data, piechart_options)

    var barchart_options = {
        title : 'Bar Chart: How Much Products Sold By Last Night',
        width : 400,
        height : 300,
        legend : 'none'
    }
    var barchart = new google.visualisation.BarChart(document
            .getElementById('barchart_div'));               
    barchart.draw(data, barchart_options)
}           

});
```

I am getting an object back from my DB query, so I think that part is right, which is an array with 6 objects:

```
0: Object { id: "1", name: "Product1", quantity: "2" }
​1: Object { id: "2", name: "Product2", quantity: "3" }
​2: Object { id: "3", name: "Product3", quantity: "4" }
​3: Object { id: "4", name: "Product4", quantity: "2" }
​4: Object { id: "5", name: "Product5", quantity: "6" }
​5: Object { id: "6", name: "Product6", quantity: "11" }
```

For what it is worth my php code is as follows:

data.php

```
<?php
require_once 'database.php';
$stmt = $conn->prepare('select * from product');
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo json_encode($results); 
?>
```

database.php

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=192.168.99.100;dbname=demo','root', 'root');
?>
```

Note: [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example) version is similar but slightly different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can actually use

`google.charts.load`

in place of

`$(document).ready`

and it should be with a z not s

`visualization`

not

`visualisation`

try it like this...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url:"data.php",
    dataType : "JSON",
    success : function(result) {
      drawChart(result);
    }
  });
});

function drawChart(result) {
    var data = new google.visualization.Datatable();
    data.addColumn('string','Name');
    data.addColumn('number','Quantity');
    $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
        data.addRow([ obj.name, parseInt(obj.quantity) ]);
    });

    var piechart_options = {
        title : 'Pie Chart: How Much Products Sold By Last Night',
        width : 400,
        height : 300
    }
    var piechart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document
            .getElementById('piechart_div'));
    piechart.draw(data, piechart_options)

    var barchart_options = {
        title : 'Bar Chart: How Much Products Sold By Last Night',
        width : 400,
        height : 300,
        legend : 'none'
    }
    var barchart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document
            .getElementById('barchart_div'));
    barchart.draw(data, barchart_options)
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I tried replacing the s with z, but now I get this `TypeError: google.visualization.Datatable is not a constructor`. Then I tried using `google.charts.load` in stead but get the same constructor error. any obvious ideas?

Comment: Thanks I got it it was this line `var data = new google.visualization.Datatable();` should be uppercase `t` in Datatable e.g `var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();` details details....think ishud go to bed :)